# rufus scheduler first monday every 3 months

Tags: rufus-scheduler, resque-scheduler

Is there a way to do rufus-scheduler for first monday every 3 months?  Is it '0 0 * 3,6,9,12 first#1'?  I am trying to use resque-scheduler.  It seems to depend on rufus version 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rufus-scheduler 2.0 documentation is at https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/two/README.rdoc

It should be `"0 0 * 3,6,9,12 mon#1"`.